# cannot read from a file by line using fstream; read by whole file ok

Tags: c++, file-io

1.i am trying to read a file line by line, yet it will not. i previously was reading the entire file in one step without a problem. i changed the vector receiving the data to a local vector as an experiment (without success). i suspect i doing something obviously wrong, except to me.

```
int
full_file_read( std::vector<std::string> &data ,
                const std::string& filename ,
                bool is_binary )
{
    std::string line ;
    std::ios_base::openmode openmode = std::ios::ate | std::ios::in ;

    if ( is_binary )
    {
        openmode |= std::ios::binary ;
    }

    std::fstream file( filename , openmode ) ;

    if ( !file )
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't open input file! "
            << filename << std::endl ;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> text ;
    // to verify that it likes the push back for data is not the problem

    if ( file.is_open() )
    {
        while ( std::getline( file , line ) )
        {
            text.push_back( line ) ;
            // data.push_back( line ) ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Opening of " << filename 
            << " failed!" << std::endl ;
    }

    std::cout << "file contents: " << std::endl ;

    for ( auto const& c : line )
    {
        std::cout << c << ' ' << std::endl ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

2.when running without using debug, i get a seg-fault. when in gdb, the while loop does not execute. data file is as follows

```
i have a comment here
and another over there
yet another in somewhere unknown
for reasons only (dr) who noses
NumParticles|SimWidth|SimHeight|ViewWidth|ViewHeight|Softener|Zoom|MouseX|MouseY|MassMin|MassMax|CenterMass|DiskMin|DiskMax
10000000,327680,327680,1366,768,10,1,0,0,1,2,100000,2000000,5
```

tia

Comment: i made that change, and thanks for pointing the error out. now for the weird part: it reads the file, echos the lines and gets to the return statement, but does not.it jumps back to open statement. strangeness!!

Answer (score 1):

`std::ios::ate` means to open at the *end* of the file. You generally only use this if you're writing to the file, you don't want to use it when you're reading. By including it here you get an end-of-file on your very first `getline`.

I can't explain the segfault, that would generally be caused by undefined behavior. Perhaps it's in the code after this function returns.

Comment: i made that change, and thanks for pointing the error out. now for the weird part: it reads the file, echos the lines and gets to the return statement, but does not.it jumps back to open statement. strangeness!! (pardon the redudant remarks as i am just getting used to this)

Comment: never mind! now the trouble is in a calling function, so lets call this solved/closed